# Aptana Studio 3.6.1 Won't Download

Tags: download

I'm trying to download Apatana Studio 3.6.1. on Chrome but after I put in my email address and clicked the download button, it took me back to the top of the page. I tried it a few more times and I've still got this problem. I also tried it on Microsoft Edge and it did the same thing.

Please help, I need this software for my class.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late, but this GitHub issue documents where you can download the necessary files.

https://github.com/aptana/studio3/issues/403